# How to retrieve Account holder's name from Yodlee

Tags: yodlee, financial

In the docs it is mentioned that account holder's name is present in the Yodlee DB https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Bank_Account  .

Which Yodlee API call can be used to retrieve the name of the account holder? 
I need this to identify and verify customer's account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If particular Bank site provides the account holder name, and Yodlee is able to scrape the same. You can get it from the following APIs.
getItemSummaryForItem1- (if using container based approach)
getItemSummariesForSite- (if using Site Based approach)